# Order products by price issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to order products by price with one link for low to high and the other high to low,
and I got this error: "Missing argument 3 for App\Http\Controllers\ShopController::products()"  when im opening the 'content.products', page.
this is the function in the controller:

```
public function products(Request $request,$category_url,$sort){
    Product::getProducts($category_url, self:: $data);
    if ($category1 = Categorie::where('url', '=', $category_url)->first()) {

       $products = Product::where('categorie_id', $category1->getAttribute('id'))->orderBy('price', $sort)->get();

        return view('content.products', self::$data , compact('products', 'sort')); 
    }
}
```

this is the route:

```
  Route::get('shop/{category_url}/sorting-{sort}','ShopController@products');
```

those are the link from the view, the view is content.products

```
  <a href="  {{ url('shop/'.$category['url'].'/sorting-asc')}}" 
 style="color:black"> High to low</a> |
    <a href="  {{ url('shop/'.$category['url'].'/sorting-desc')}}" style="color:black">Low to high</a>
```

Comment: you didn't update your route, others may get confused

Comment: forgot to update here, updated

Answer (score 0):

I think your link would look more elegant if you leave everything like a friendly link. So, if you want to do so, you can change your route with

`Route::get('shop/{category_url}/sorting-{sort}','ShopController@products');`

and add a parameter to your function

`public function products($category_url, $sort){`

then you don't need a request if you don't use it anywhere else. Also then you need to remove this line

`$sort = $request->get('sort', 'asc');`

And everything should work. Good luck! Sorry if doesn't work, can't test it right now.

Comment: Thanks, but I got an error    Argument 3 passed to App\Http\Controllers\ShopController::products() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given

Comment: Argument 3 passed to App\Http\Controllers\ShopController::products() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given

Comment: okay, looks like it is neccessary, then add request :D `public function products($category_url, $sort,Request $request){` and don't forget, that you need to link to `{{ url('shop/'.$category['url'].'/sorting-asc')}}` and`{{ url('shop/'.$category['url'].'/sorting-desc')}}`

Comment: I added the links and the request but it still showing the same error,       
  `  
       public function products($category_url,$sort, Request $request){
    Product::getProducts($category_url, self:: $data);
    if ($category1 = Categorie::where('url', '=', $category_url)->first()) {
      
       $products = Product::where('categorie_id', $category1->getAttribute('id'))->orderBy('price', $sort)->get();

        return view('content.products', self::$data , compact('products', 'sort')); 
    }`

Comment: Try to put the request in first place before $category_url

Comment: I Tried: public function products(Request $request, $category_url,$sort) still it's the same error:(

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, then :(

Comment: You can add current problem to this question so maybe anyone will know what to do, @RO.IT

Comment: @RO.IT glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Check those 3 variables in this code and it will give you more hints about your problem.

```
public function products($category_url, Request $request){
    Product::getProducts($category_url, self:: $data);
    if ($category1 = Categorie::where('url', '=', $category_url)->first()) {
         dd($category1->id); // 1 check this

         $sort = $request->get('sort', 'asc');
         dd($sort); // 2 check again

         // 3 check 'categorie_id' if there is any typo
         $products = Product::where('categorie_id', $category1->id)
        ->orderBy('price', $sort)
        ->get();

        return view('content.products', self::$data , compact('products', 'sort')); 
    }
}
```